# python: how to create spawn a websockets server in a thread?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I would like to have a Server object which would support an API similar to:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    server = Server()                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    server.start()                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    time.sleep(3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    server.stop()
```

The reason why I do not use asyncio.run in this main function, is because I am planning to use instances of Server in various context, including in pytest fixtures.

Here an unsuccessful attempt:

```py
import asyncio                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
import threading                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
import time                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
import websockets                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
async def run(                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    websocket, request_stop: threading.Event, exited_future: asyncio.Future                                                                                                                                                       
) -> None:
    """
    Toy server socket example in which messages are received until the request_stop event
    is set (externally). When exiting, it sets the value of the exited_future
    (as a signal the server should also exit).
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    while True:                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=0.5)                                                                                                                                                                 
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:                                                                                                                                                                                              
            pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        if request_stop.is_set():                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            break                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        exited_future.set_result(None)                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
async def run_server(                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    request_stop: threading.Event, exited_future: asyncio.Future                                                                                                                                                                  
):         
    """
    Spawn a socket server serving the 'run' function. When 'request_stop' is
    set, 'run' exits and set the value of 'exited_future', resulting 
    in this function also exiting.
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    async with websockets.serve(                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        lambda websocket, path: run(websocket, request_stop, exited_future),                                                                                                                                                      
        "localhost",                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        1734,                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ):                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        await exited_future                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
class Server:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    def start(self):
        """
        Spawning "run_server" in a thread.
        """                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        self._request_stop = threading.Event()                                                                                                                                                                                    
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()                                                                                                                                                                                           
        self._exited_future = loop.create_future()                                                                                                                                                                                
        self._thread = threading.Thread(                                                                                                                                                                                          
            target=loop.run_until_complete,                                                                                                                                                                                       
            args=(run_server(self._request_stop, self._exited_future)),                                                                                                                                                           
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        self._thread.start()                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    def stop(self):
        """
        Setting the request_stop event, which signals to the 
        websocket "run" client (and consequently to the 'run_server')
        that it should exit. 
        """                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        self._request_stop.set()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        time.sleep(0.5)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        self._exited_future.set_result(None)                                                                                                                                                                                      
        self._thread.join()                  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # running the server for 3 seconds                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    server = Server()                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    server.start()                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    time.sleep(3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    server.stop()
```

It 'kind of' work, i.e. it receives message, but also has various issues, e.g.

It starts with a warning:

> DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

and it crashes when exiting:

> in stop
> self._exited_future.set_result(None)
> asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: invalid state

But rather than fixing these issue, I would like to ask if at least the global approach is correct. It feels inadequate to mix threading and asyncio.